# Cannot boot Ubuntu 20.4, not showing anything

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu with a USB. It worked OK at first, but when I shut down the laptop for the 1st time and tried to boot it again it showed a message saying " unrecognized AMD processor un CpuInfoAMD" and then shows a black screen. I got a Ryzen 5800h (with Radeon graphics) and an RTX 3050. I changed NVIDIA drivers to oficial ones and installed Radeon Linux drivers provided by AMD.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you had a problem with the installation of the OS, you can try these thing:

Check BIOS settings: Enter the BIOS settings on your laptop and make sure that the CPU is recognized correctly. You may need to update the BIOS to the latest version, which may resolve the issue.

Boot options: Try booting into Ubuntu with different boot options, such as recovery mode or with a different kernel version. You can access these options by pressing the ESC key during boot or by editing the GRUB menu.

Check hardware compatibility: Make sure that the Ubuntu operating system is compatible with your hardware components. You can check the Ubuntu Hardware Compatibility List to ensure that your hardware is supported.

Reinstall Ubuntu: If none of the above steps work, you may need to reinstall Ubuntu on your laptop

Comment: The problem is I already reinstalled it. I had Windows but, for privacy and performance problems, decided to install Ubuntu. I had the same problem so just reinstalled it and wiped all the data. Another thing: sometimes I kinda manage to boot it. I don't know why, but when I access the ESC menu and I select Ubuntu I'm sometimes able to boot formally. It doesn't work always.

Comment: Try the above solutions also you can try running a filesystem check or repair tool, such as fsck or boot-repair, you can also try different boot option such as nomodeset or acpi=off

Comment: I just realised something. When I use the NVIDIA drivers I get this issue, but  changing to open source drivers fixes it. I need Nvidia drivers because I'm gonna be using DaVinci Resolve and Blender, which don't works as fluidly without the official drivers. What can I do?

Comment: When O can't boot, I access the bootloader menu and select "advanced options for Ubuntu". There I start Ubuntu with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic instead of .35 and it works fine.

Comment: Try with the latest nvidia drivers, try different version, see with the Davinci Resolve and Blender community if they had your problem on ubuntu, you can even contact Nvidia support